# Recover overwritten CCTV footage from hard drive

Tags: filesystems, mount, data-recovery, forensics

I am trying to recover deleted footage from a DVR. I pulled the hdd(Toshiba DT01ABA100v) from the DVR to look at the data in the drive and run carving tools(foremost and scalpel). My problem is that I am unable to mount the hdd. The following are the outputs of some of the commands I tried

```
file -s /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb: DOS/MBR boot sector MS-MBR Windows 7 english at offset 0x163 "Invalid partition table" at offset 0x17b "Error loading operating system" at offset 0x19a "Missing operating system", disk signature 0x26a0a7cf

mount /dev/sdb /mnt/recdrive
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb, missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

Is there something I can use to find the file system and be able to mount the hdd?

Comment: You sure it's not `/dev/sdb1` or something?

Comment: @frostschutz yes, I am sure.

Comment: What does `fdisk -l` say about that disk?

Comment: @casey `Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x26d0d7cf`

Answer (score -1):

file -s /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb: DOS/MBR boot sector MS-MBR Windows 7 english at offset 0x163 "Invalid partition table" at offset 0x17b "Error loading operating system" at offset 0x19a "Missing operating system", disk signature 0x26a0a7cf

mount /dev/sdb /mnt/recdrive
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb, missing codepage or helper program, or

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/417777)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).